# What is the right Stack Exchange site for a browser behavior question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Some feature of my web app written in JavaScript depends on the caching behaviour of browsers. However there is a inconsistency when my web app runs in Chrome as opposed to Safari.

On the face of it, it is not a programming issue per se because I am asking about why there is a difference in caching strategy (and hopefully looking for a solution).

However the issue does have an impact to my application functionality.

Should I still post the question on Stack Overflow? If not, what other Stack Exchange site is the best fit?

Comment: Obligatory: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Meta StackExchange

Comment: @aba "Is this type of question on topic for Stack Overflow?" is a perfectly valid question for Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, but I think it'd fit more StackExchange since it's about StackExchange in general. I might be wrong though

Comment: @AbAppletic Now we're talking meta-meta-stack overflow. Or stack exchange? ;D

Comment: @u8y7541 umm...

Comment: @AbAppletic if you're talking about if a question belongs on meta stack overflow or meta stack exchange isn't it double meta

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Whilst it is entirely possible that the issue is the caching behaviour, it is still a problem you are having with getting your code to work. So just base your question around what you're trying to solve and note that you believe it is do to caching behaviour. If it turns out that is the issue then the answers you should get should describe why that is so, if not then you still have your problem solved

So when asking

- Include a MCVE of the actual problem you're trying to solve
- Mention that you believe the issue is do to caching behaviour

A great/good answer would mention why the caching is done as it is (if that is the issue).

Answer (score 34):

Sounds reasonable fit for SO (assuming you get MCVE)...

Make sure to ask practical part of your question so, not "why there is a difference in caching strategy" (which is "because code is different, duh"). If you really interested in later part finding corresponding RFC and asking about how browsers comply to particular requirement would be better way to spin it.